# Ubuntu doesn't show output and input devices

Tags: 16.04, sound, input, output

I cant't control the volume, it's muted but the sound comes out anyway, it only stops if I plug headphones.
Besides that, in the settings it is not showing the output and input devices, so I can't hear music in my headset.

[image]